# cakephp flash component produces error

Tags: php, cakephp

Am learning Cakephp. In my PostsController the line

`$this->Flash->success(__('Your post has been saved.'));`

gives error as below

> Error:'Call to a member function success() on a non-object'

What can be the reason please?

Comment: Sorry about my previous message - you need to show more code, the error message simply means the flash component hasn't been loaded.

Comment: make sure you are using calling session component in your controller.                             var $components = array('Session');

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the fact that you do not load the FlashComponent. To fix it, in the PostsController class definition, insert the following
var $components = array ('Flash');

Answer (score 0):

You haven´t loaded Session component.
Do it by  var $components = array('Session');